# Как ввести данные Input и Output на javascript для решение задачи?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, веб-программирование

Я пытаюсь решить данную задачу http://www.spoj.com/problems/HOTELS/

Я сделал такое решение

```js
var A = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5];
    var B = [];
    var n = 5
    var m = 12
    big = -1;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum=0;
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            sum += A[j];
            if (sum < m) { B[i] = sum; continue; }//B[i] становится равным сумме
            if (sum > m) { B[i] = (sum - A[j]); break; }
            if (sum == m) {
              B[i] = sum //B[i] становится равным сумме 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (B[i] > big)
            big = B[i];
    }
    alert(big);
```

Теперь мне нужно как-то отправить решение через "Submit solution" и здесь я испытываю проблемы. Как правильно изменить мой код, чтобы мое решения приняли?
В поисках решения на мой вопрос я наткнулся на эту ссылку и увидел, что для js нужна такая конструкция.

```js
while((num = readline()) != 42) {
print(num);

}
```

Эта конструкция мне не понятна, ведь это даже не javascript. Подскажите как изменить мой код, чтобы программа приняла мой ответ?

Comment: Там есть примеры для различных языков.
https://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_35

JavaScrypt там используется не в чистом виде а из под движков
JavaScript (rhino 1.7.7)

    System.out.println(line);

и JavaScript (SMonkey 24.2.0).

    print(num);
Там же тесты не для браузеров а для обычных программ. JavaScrypt там можно использовать для специальных движков, добавляющих функционал программ. Или еще есть Node.js.

Comment: Вообще там после регистрации нужно сделать простейший тест. Как раз там и надо разбираться как ввод и вывод делать.

Answer (score 1):

тебе нельзя жестко задавать массив в коде. Все параметры должны вводиться в программу, например с клавиатуры или через файл. Там может быть очень много вариантов задачи этой и на каждый вход надо сгенерировать верный ответ

Answer (score -2):

Посмотри на **prompt**: http://javascript.ru/PROMPT .
Можно весь ввод получить как строку разделенную запятыми или пробелами и затем разделить их в массив.

```
let str = prompt('Введите числа');
let input = str.split(',');
```

Comment: скорее всего такой подход не сработает, чтобы программа приняла решение нужно использовать серверные методы.
Я нашел такой пример 
while((num = readline()) != 42) {
print(num);
}

но как сделать похожее в моем случае, пока не знаю

Comment: На сервере может только nodejs. Посмотри тогда на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396020/is-there-a-way-to-read-standard-input-with-javascript, http://qaru.site/questions/67081/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node

Comment: @selimoves нет, не только. Node.js сейчас на слуху как внебраузерная реализация JS, но он не первый и уж тем более не единственный в своём роде.